# Why does Golang's MD5 distribution not appear to be uniform?

Tags: go, hash, md5

I fully expect I have a bug somewhere or am misunderstanding something, but why does the following code not appear to exhibit uniform distribution?

```
func TestMD5(t *testing.T) {
    n := 50000
    counts := map[uint32]int{} // # of hashes per 1/nth shard

    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        hash := md5.Sum(newUUID())
        result := binary.BigEndian.Uint32(hash[:4])
        counts[result/uint32(n)]++
    }

    dupeShards := 0
    dupeEntries := 0
    for _, count := range counts {
        if count > 1 {
            dupeShards++
            dupeEntries += count - 1
        }
    }
    t.Logf("%d inputs hashed to the same %d shards as other inputs.", dupeEntries, dupeShards)

    if len(counts) < n*95/100 {
        t.Fatalf("%d populated shards not within 5%% of expected %d uniform distribution!", len(counts), n)
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/05mA0Dl9GBG

—

Explanation of code:

- MD5 50k random UUIDs.
- For each MD5 sum, take the first 4 bytes and convert to a uint32.
- Divide the result by 50k (using truncated/floor division) to distribute the hashes into 50k evenly spaced shards.

==> I'd expect the 50k MD5 sums to be ~evenly distributed across the 50k shards, but I consistently see only ~38k shards populated, with clumping in ~10k of the shards:

```
main.go:29: 12075 inputs hashed to the same 9921 shards as other inputs.
main.go:32: 37925 populated shards not within 5% of expected 50000 uniform distribution!
```

I can repro this with other hashes too (e.g. FNV), so I'm guessing I'm misunderstanding something. Thank you for the help!

Comment: That's normal. That's what drawing from a uniform distribution is supposed to look like.

Comment: Have you compared that to other MD5 implementations? AFAIK, it's a defined algorithm and implementations may differ, but not in their results! So, the "go"-part of your question is a red herring already.

Comment: Also, you're throwing the outputs into 1+(2^32)/50000 buckets, not 50000. If you had thrown them into 50000 buckets, you would have seen even more outputs land in the same bucket.

Comment: @user2357112: can you explain the buckets comment? I'm dividing (with truncation) the space of all possible `1+(2^32)` values by 50000, so that _is_ 50k buckets, no? That also seems correct given the answer below since only 38k of those buckets are populated.

Comment: Ah, I realize now! I need to `%`, not `/`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is absolutely normal behavior, and doesn't show any bias or incorrectness of the MD5 implementation.

What you are doing is (very close to) taking 50,000 random numbers between 0 and 49,999. When you do this, it's almost certain that many of the numbers will be repeated, and therefore that some numbers won't appear. It would in fact be very unlikely that the 50,000 numbers should all be different with absolutely no repetitions.

You can test this with a six-sided dice - if you throw it 6 times, you're very unlikely to get all six numbers, and much more likely to see around 3, 4 or 5 of them, with one, two or three repetitions. It's also related to the so-called [birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

Another example of this phenomenon is the 'Panini sticker question'. A Panini sticker album is a book with space for around 600 football stickers which commemorate the World Cup of soccer. Each one is numbered and different, and they feature randomly in packets. You have to get one of each number to complete the album. Suppose that you bought exactly the right number of stickers to fill the album. It would be extremely lucky if you were able to fill the album perfectly, without having any doubles or missing stickers. In fact you have to buy on average a large multiple of the number of stickers in order to get at least one of each (if you don't swap duplicates with other collectors).

The number of different values 0-49,999 which appear and the number which show 'clumping' can be calculated mathematically. I'm not sure exactly how you measure clumping. But the value of 38K populated values will be quite stable from one trial to the next, even though the actual values you see will change.

In fact, the expected number of populated values is (1 - 1/e)n, where n is the number of possible values, and e is the mathematical constant 2.718281828... The answer for n=50000 is 31606. You won't always get this value of course, but all results should be within a few hundred or so (spitballing here). You made a slight mistake in your program so I haven't been able to decipher the relevant calculation that gives you ~37000.

Comment: It's actually more like taking 50000 random numbers between 0 and 85899, because the bucketing logic is wrong. That confused me for a bit - I was expecting closer to 31600 populated buckets.

Comment: If you're curious, the 2018 album has 682 slots. You can expect to buy about 4800 stickers to fill it if you don't trade (and don't order the last 50 from Panini): https://youtu.be/aKPkQCys86c

Comment: Makes sense! Thank you — this is very helpful. I'm very curious to know how to calculate the expected "clumping" if you or anyone has any pointers there. :)